# Place Views in different positions

Tags: android, imageview, position

I want to place Icons (Imageviews) on a bigger Imageview. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<Icon> icons = new ArrayList<Icons>;
for(Icon icon : icons){
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
   iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   iv.setImageBitmap(icon.getBitMap());
   iv.setPosition(icon.getX(),icon.getY()); //Thats the line I need to know
   myLayout.addView(iv); 
}
```

but the problem is I can't find a way to make it efficient and knowing which imageview was clicked.

Comment: Knowing which ImageView was clicked can be done using `Tag` inside the View's `onClickListener() `

Comment: Where do you want to put the icons ? is it a linear layout and you want to keep the imagesViews like a list and keep icons in the centre of each image or what ?

Comment: no something like X:Y   (100,200) or (212,50) or (523, 321) you know what i mean?

Comment: maybe you can do that using padding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out which view was clicked, apply a tag to it and then check the tag of the view passed with `onClick()`

```
ArrayList<Icon> icons = new ArrayList<Icons>;
for(int i = 0; i < icons.size(); i++) {
   Icon icon = icons.get(i);
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
   iv.setTag(i);
   iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   iv.setImageBitmap(icon.getBitMap());
   iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener({
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           iconClicked(view);
       }
   });
   myLayout.addView(iv); 
}


public void iconClicked(View view) {
    switch((Integer) view.getTag())
        case 0:
            //...
            break;
        case 1: 
            //...
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you an idea how to solve the x,y problem, but this works fine

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need for placement, @Ribisl? I see that you're trying to position them but I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: there is no "setPosition" method

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my positioning problem you can just do:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setX(xPosition);
imageView.setY(YPosition);
```

The question with, which Image was clicked, answered @Hobo Joe very nicely, with this sample!

```
ArrayList<Icon> icons = new ArrayList<Icons>;
for(int i = 0; i < icons.size(); i++) {
   Icon icon = icons.get(i);
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
   iv.setTag(i);
   iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   iv.setImageBitmap(icon.getBitMap());
   iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener({
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           iconClicked(view);
       }
   });
   myLayout.addView(iv); 
}


public void iconClicked(View view) {
    switch((Integer) view.getTag())
        case 0:
            //...
            break;
        case 1: 
            //...
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```